# What will happen in Kubernetes if etcd stops working?

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, etcd

While running a complete cluster if suddenly etcd stops working, then what will happen?

Will pods services and deployments continue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `etcd cluster` is considered failed if the majority of `etcd members` have permanently failed.

After the `etcd cluster` failure, all running workload might continue operating. However due to etcd role, Kubernetes cannot make any changes to its current state. Although the scheduled pods might continue to run, no new pods can be scheduled.
So applications running in Kubernetes cluster might continue to serve traffic but `etcd` cluster should be [recovered](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/configure-upgrade-etcd/#restoring-an-etcd-cluster) as soon as possible.

You can find more information about `etcd's` role in Kubernetes in [Rancher docs](https://rancher.com/blog/2019/2019-01-29-what-is-etcd/).